# Retrofit form data response not same as postman

Tags: android, retrofit, postman, okhttp, form-data

I am trying to simulate a POST form-data request from postman with retrofit 2 in my android application.

I am using RetroFit 2.3.0

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
```

My postman query looks as [follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nueoV.png)

I also have some headers which are:

- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
- User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36

and my response is:

```
[
    {
        "lecture": "http://2xx.xxx/videos/6xxxxxx6oxsx.mp4",
        "quality": "720p",
        "type": "video/mp4"
    }
}
```

That is the correct response. However, when i try simulate this request with RetroFit I dont get the result back like postman. Here is my RetroFit data.

```
@POST("/admin.php")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<University> fetchLecture(@Field("action") String action,
                                      @Field("id") String ids,
                                      @Field("server") int server,
                                      @Field("nonce") String nonce);
```

Then I call the method:

```
private void getLecture(String dataID, String nonce){
            final String ACTION = "video_info";
            final int SERVER = 1;

            mAPIService.fetchLecture(ACTION,dataID,SERVER,nonce).enqueue(new Callback<University>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<University> call, Response<University> response) {
                    Log.d("dataid", "success");
                    Log.d("dataid","API call was a success. Response:");
                    Log.d("dataid", response.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<University> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("dataid", "Unable to submit post to API.");
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

        }
```

here is the http log:

```
03-12 18:13:54.852 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: --> POST myendpoint....php http/1.1
03-12 18:13:54.852 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
03-12 18:13:54.853 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 181
03-12 18:13:54.853 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: action=video_info&id=jlIR0pR1ZDb0MzVGtSSlkxRy9tY2l0ZGJud1E9PQ%3D%3D&server=1&nonce=f326b41b57
03-12 18:13:54.853 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: --> END POST (181-byte body)
03-12 18:13:54.993 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK 
03-12 18:13:54.993 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: Server: VPZ
03-12 18:13:54.993 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: Date: Mon, 12 Mar 2018 18:13:07 GMT
03-12 18:13:54.993 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html
03-12 18:13:54.993 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 134
03-12 18:13:54.993 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: Connection: keep-alive
03-12 18:13:54.993 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: PipeGuard=d00a56603601f7dbda84a42d5654df65; path=/
03-12 18:13:54.993 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: P3P: CP="CUR ADM OUR NOR STA NID", policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml"
03-12 18:13:54.993 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
03-12 18:13:54.993 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache
03-12 18:13:54.994 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: Pragma: public
03-12 18:13:54.994 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
03-12 18:13:54.994 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: <html><head><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=http://myendpoint.....php"></head><body></body></html>
03-12 18:13:54.994 12775-12930/? D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (134-byte body)
```

can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Your response json is wrong format of json
2. try to add encoded = true in your fields

Comment: are you missing "Accept: application/json" in header.

Comment: the response that you have demonstrated and you are assuming correct is an **INVALID JSON FORMAT**

Comment: @PhanDinhThai could you give me an example please?

Comment: @Raghunandan ive tried this didnt make a difference